# Is searching first with std::map::find then using [], to retrieve the value, optimised usually?

Tags: c++, search, stdmap

I find often this pattern in some codebase I work with:

```
   std::map<std::string, std::string> mymap;

   ...

   if (mymap.find(key) != mymap.end())
   {
       return mymap[key];
   }
```

I know this can be replaced by

```
   std::map<std::string, std::string> mymap;

   ...

   auto it = mymap.find(key) 
   if (it != mymap.end())
   {
       return it->second;
   }
```

But I was wondering if, in practice, the first version would get optimised to not search twice anyway?

Comment: First one not only cannot be optimized but also cannot be used in const method. So I bet your codebase do not follow const correctness either, otherwise they will find this unconvinient to use it too often.

Comment: The equivalent conditional would be this: `if (auto const it = mymap.find(key); it != mymap.end()) { return it->second; }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it will not be optimized. The pattern is too high level.

You could preferentially just do this instead:

```
 std::map<std::string, std::string> mymap;

   ...

   auto it = mymap.find(key);
   if ( it != mymap.end())
   {
       return it->second;
   }
```

You can check on the benchmark below:

```cpp
int findOptim( int key )
{
   auto it = mymap.find(key); 
   if (it != mymap.end())
   {
       return it->second;
   }
   return -1;
}

int findTrivial( int key ) {
    if ( mymap.find(key) != mymap.end() ) {
        return mymap[key];
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Benchmark: https://quick-bench.com/q/7mFWe8jlXD7J9GTDMNSiZdcGCgY

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what the OP posted as the second option. Your post should be a comment than an answer.

Comment: @ViktorLiehr Thanks for the suggestion. I extended the answer!

Comment: @ViktorLiehr Why shoud it be a comment?  The very first sentence literally answers the OP's: *No it will not be optimized. The pattern is too high level.*

Comment: I'm often surprised by what sneaky smurf people put into compilers, and it could be recognized with crafty enough code, so I wouldn't say "not optimized" in the global sense. I would be on page with "probably not optimized" and examples showing one or more of the big three compilers not optimizing. Pretty close to what you just did.

Comment: @NathanOliver the answer was extended quite a bit after its initial version which was rather bare boned

Comment: @NoleKsum Thanks for the very great extended answer (edited). In the original it appeared like you`re repeating the answer already privided by the OP.

My apologies for that. Your edited post look much better now. Thanks.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I know, it was the version of the answer I was talking about, but that answer was still an answer even before the benchmark.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number True! It might be that one Intel or pg compiler have this pattern nailed. However I would guess that if they do, it would be in some tool like `clang-tidy` for example. Worth checking!

Comment: @NoleKsum I think you wanted to tag me with that comment. Not much value to my comment post-edit.

Comment: @user4581301 Why dont you get yourself a **NAME** like normal decent people do? :)

Comment: Partly because I wasn't sure which of my names I should use here, but mostly because I'm an anonymous coward.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number True, I extended the answer after Viktor Liehr's comment on top. I actually thanked him on the 2nd comment.

Comment: @user4581301 “What is your name?” “My name is Legion,” he replied, “for we are many.”

Comment: Thanks for the quick bench link, I didn’t know this website: it’s very nifty